# Trying to find proper Regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a regular expression which matches with both of the following urls:

```
http://honey.myPage.com/national/
http://honey.myPage.com/national
```

i mean url with ending slash and without ending slash
i am able to make following pattern which is currently only recognizing pattern with slash only.
can anyone suggest me either a different pattern which can recognize both kind of urls

```
/\.myPage\.com\/(\D+[\/])+(index.htm[l]?)?/
```

Any Help will be appericiated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A questionmark stands for 0 or 1. So you have to add a questionmark after the slash.
Change it to this:

```
/\.myPage\.com\/(\D+\/?)+(index.htm[l]?)?/
```

Comment: You don't need a character class for single character.

Comment: Thank you. This was a direct copy, so I didn't evaluate it.

Answer (score 2):

Could you clarify your intent with **\D** ?
it matches any **non digit**, so would match also /, ?, !, ... 
I don't think this was your intent?

Assuming you want to match:

```
.myPage.com/pretty/mutch/any/uri/provided
.myPage.com/pretty/mutch/any/uri/provided/
.myPage.com/pretty/mutch/any/uri/provided/index.htm
.myPage.com/pretty/mutch/any/uri/provided/index.html
```

I'd go with something like this:

```
\.myPage\.com(\/\w+)+?(\/(index\.html?)?)?
```

`(\/\w+)+?` - matches `/sometext`, repeated one or multiple times, but as little as possible to work (necessary to handle the rest of the rule properly)

`(\/(index\.html?)?)?` should be decomposed:

**(**/(index.html?)?**)?** - the whole block is optional

/(index.html?)? - would match `/` or `/index.htm` or `/index.html`

Hope this helps.